# Selenium crashes when passed to 2nd Form

Tags: c#, selenium, c#-4.0, .net-4.0, selenium-chromedriver

I have a class for using Selenium because I want it to work in two forms and I've been told to do so:

```
public class selenium1
    {
        public ChromeDriver driverx;

        public ChromeDriver create()
        {
            driverx = new ChromeDriver();
            return driverx;
        }
        public ChromeDriver getDriver2()
        {
            return driverx;
        }
    }
```

In my first form i use it like that, and it works good.

```
ChromeDriver driver;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        vulcan2.selenium1 asd = new vulcan2.selenium1();
        driver = asd.create();
    }
```

But later on in the second, when i want to load an other site using the same Driver:

```
        ChromeDriver driver;
        private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            vulcan2.selenium1 asd = new vulcan2.selenium1();
            driver = asd.getDriver2();
            MessageBox.Show("dsadsadsa");
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://google.com");
        }
```

It just freezes and crashes my app. How can I fix it?

Comment: As the others below have said, you'll want to fix your singleton implementation.  But that doesn't explain why it's crashing.    I suspect that your driver isn't working in the first place as Form1 does not perform any operations like navigating or selecting elements, while frmMain_Load has a navigate action.   My guess is Selenium is launching the browser, but the bindings might not be working with that version of the browser so it's failing on the Navigate command.

Answer (score 1):

In each method you're instantiating a new instance of the selenium1 class. Each selenium1 object will have it's own driverx and therefore will create new drivers for each.

What I would reccommend is to make driverx a public static member, and in your create method check if this object is null, instantiate a ChromeDriver if it is, and then return the driverx member.

```
public static ChromeDriver driverx = null;

public ChromeDriver create()
{
    if(driverx == null)
        driverx = new ChromeDriver();
    return driverx;
}
```

You could also just make your selenium1 class a singleton class as that would best fit your needs it seems.